# jQuery code to ommit the top and bottom parts of iframe source

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, frame

Basically we have this website which is a retailer of bigger brands.

They want to include the brand's own catalog which is on the brands website.

Problem is, the brand itself is selling their product on their website, too.

Is there way to actively hide the top parts (first 500px of height and last 300px of height) of the webpage inside the iframe?

I've tried many methods but they either failed or I got "unsafe" method errors such as this:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.siteaddress.com/ from frame with URL http://www.othersiteaddress.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

I don't want to change anything on their website, I just want to hide the top and bottom parts.
What makes this harder is that some pages inside the iframe will have different heights, so the only way is to ommit the first 500 px and the last 300px of height. But how, the last few hours didn't help me find it out.

Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do user's also need to scroll within the frame?

Comment: @Fresheyeball yes, the page is very long (always has vertical scrollbars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There are fancy things you could try, but it would actually be easier to scrape and interact with the brand's website on the server side.

So No. Just No.

Comment: So scraping would be easier than using iframes? can scraping with PHP act like an iframe but modified? or will it be too content specific, e.g. when they change their website everything will fall apart? Thanks

Comment: When they change their website everything will fall apart anyway.

Comment: Yep, I realised that as soon as I added the comment. What I meant was that what are the differences between scraping with PHP and using iframes? will scraping be too limiting?

Comment: The difference is they are completely different approaches.

Comment: Php scraping will be totally different experience, you will be scraping and then manually rebuilding each piece of functionality for each brand with php by hand, posting back to their server, and re-scraping. Then if they change anything you have a nightmare on your hands.

Comment: I see. Thanks for being so helpful. I will go and study how scraping really works and decide accordingly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you're most likely not going to be able to achieve what you are after.

Longer answer:

To run javascript on the page you are embedding it either needs to be from the same domain (as to not fall foul of browser cross-domain blocking of your javascript), or modified to include specific scripts to allow communication.

Even if you had access make changes to the website being included in the iframe, which it appears you do not, this would still cause many issues. As already indicated, pages would vary with content and structure, you would probably need to do something like hiding specific DOM elements such as a header/footer/container etc - which would then affect the layout, and so on.

There would be so many edge cases to account for, achieving the result you're aiming for is just not practical.

Comment: I've already found out most of what you said and they're all true. iframes are evil and working with them is such a mess. But they want this feature and before telling them it's not possible, I thought maybe there's a way to hide the iframe top and bottom parts whenever there's focus on the iframe. can't this be achieved with a local code?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really without having access to the other website - you would need to include javascript there.